# Assembly load error, getting Error! Can not find sgfplib.dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll, fingerprint

I downloaded secugen FDx Pro SDK and tried to use it in my .NET application. I added the `SecuGen.FDxSDKPro.Windows.dll` file as reference in my project. However, the SDK document also said that `sgfplib.dll` is required but no clear information of how it should be added.

When I run my application it's throwing error `Error! can not find sgfplib.dll`, I tried adding it as reference but visual studio is throwing error `sgfplib.dll could not be added, please make make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component`. I checked online for possible solutions of which I tried many like converting the dll file to .NET assembly which is not converting by the way. I will appreciate you guys response

Comment: Seems like you need to download that sgfplib.dll file and add it again as reference.  https://www.dll-files.com/sgfplib.dll.html

Comment: potential workaround: try placing the file in the bin folder

Comment: The file probably just needs to be in the directory with the other DLL.  Add it to your solution and tell VS to copy to output when it compiles.

Comment: @Thameem Have tried doing that, still visual studio isn't recognizing it as valid reference

Comment: @Y.S Thanks for the response, done that but still throwing same error

Comment: @JAZ done your suggestion as well, the error still occurring

Comment: Is it a 32bit dll?  Might have to compile for 32 bit

Answer (score 3):

I believe these files need to be in `\Windows\System32` and `\Windows\SysWOW64` respectively, not in the local .bin folder. The `SecuGen*.dll` .Net reference is looking for them there.